# Is it possible multisite in Yii?

Tags: yii, multisite

I am developing a Yii site which will be basically a multi-site.
By saying multi-site I mean there will be three different urls like as

1. www.example.com/companyA
2. www.example.com/companyB
3. www.example.com/companyB

And all these urls will have there own users and admin with their rights or privileges.

My approach is achieve this to have a single database with user types and company_id.

I am confused in if should I suppose to create separate modules for each company...NOT SURE

Also how I am gonna differentiate the request between these companies to fetch the data.

Any help will be much appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: yes you can do that.

Comment: Can you please let me know how? I mean is there any specific approach to do it?

Comment: You are using yii1 or yii2 ?.. and you need  a common database (or common tables) and a private database  (or tables) for each "site"?

Comment: Yii1...and I am planning for single database...